# Why does awk "not in" array work just like awk "in" array?

Tags: awk, gawk

Here's an awk script that attempts to set difference of two files based on their first column:

```
BEGIN{
    OFS=FS="\t"
    file = ARGV[1]
    while (getline < file)
        Contained[$1] = $1
    delete ARGV[1]
    }
$1 not in Contained{
    print $0
}
```

Here is TestFileA:

```
cat
dog
frog
```

Here is TestFileB:

```
ee
cat
dog
frog
```

However, when I run the following command:

```
gawk -f Diff.awk TestFileA TestFileB
```

I get the output just as if the script had contained "in":

```
cat
dog
frog
```

While I am uncertain about whether "not in" is correct syntax for my intent, I'm very curious about why it behaves exactly the same way as when I wrote "in".

Comment: I also couldn't find any doc about "not in", so I agree that it is not the correct syntax for my original intent, although that wasn't the actual question.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html -- this page refers to the question exactly, and the documentation explicitly indicates `indx in array` returns `true` or `0` (false) if the `indx` is in or not in the array. So to negate that, use the `!` operator. If this doesn't work, it's time to verify whether you are using `gnu awk` (which the documentation references) or `mawk` (which is typically the default).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I cannot find any [doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html#Reference-to-Elements) about `element not in array`.

Try `!(element in array)`.

---

I guess: `awk` sees `not` as an uninitialized variable, so `not` is evaluated as an empty string.

```
$1 not == $1 "" == $1
```

Comment: I can't tell from your code what you are trying to do and even if I take out the wayward 'not' bareword I still get syntax errors. Try 'awk --lint -f yourfile.awk yourdatafile

Comment: @starbolin: I think you meant for you comment to be attached to the question since it doesn't make any sense attached here. You shouldn't get any syntax errors since there's nothing (else) wrong with the script.

Answer (score 25):

I figured this one out.  The ( x in array ) returns a value, so to do "not in array", you have to do this:

```
if ( x in array == 0 )
   print "x is not in the array"
```

or in your example:

```
($1 in Contained == 0){
   print $0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is anything like you were trying to do.

```
#! /bin/awk
# will read in the  second arg file and make a hash of the token
# found in column one. Then it will read the first arg file and print any
# lines with a token in column one not matching the tokens already defined
BEGIN{
    OFS=FS="\t"
    file = ARGV[1]
    while (getline  < file)
        Contained[$1] = $1
#    delete ARGV[1]  # I don't know what you were thinking here
#    for(i in Contained) {print Contained[i]} # debuging, not just for sadists
    close (ARGV[1])
}
{
   if ($1 in  Contained){} else { print $1 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my solution for this problem I use the following `if-else` statement:

```
if($1 in contained);else{print "Here goes your code for \"not in\""}
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk commande line I use:

```
 ! ($1 in a)
$1 pattern
a array
```

Example:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}! ($1 in a) {print $1}' file1 file2
```